# And/Or Category Query

Tags: categories, query

I'm having a lot of trouble using php query_posts(array('category__and'=>array(1,3))) - it seems to be pulling anything that's in category 1 regardless of whether it's also in category 3 and I only want the posts if they exist in both categories.  And ultimately, I need a bunch of OR statements anyway, so is there a better way than query_posts to do this?

I want a page of posts that exist in a variety of multiple categories -- i.e:

categories 1 AND 3 
OR categories 1 AND 5
OR categories 1 AND 6

But not 
categories 1 AND 4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, that usage of `category__and` should be working.

As for following logic I don't think you can accomplish anything that complex with query parameters. There are several possible ways to deal with it that I can think of:

- simplify category structure and/or selection logic;
- modify raw SQL with `posts_where` filter;
- store selection criteria in post meta.

Comment: This actually was the best advice for me. I was trying to do too many things with this category select and by simplifying it, the category_and worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve something like what you're looking for with the [`tax_query`](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/) argument.

In your case (untested, may yet fail), something like this will serve to get posts (in category 1) AND (in either category 3, 5, or 6) AND (NOT in category 4):

```
$tax_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array( 1 ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array( 3, 5, 6 ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array( 4 ),
        'operator' => "NOT IN"
    ),
);

query_posts( array( 'tax_query' => $tax_query ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it using the new tax_query arguments, like so.

```
query_posts( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('term1', 'term3'),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('term1', 'term5'),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('term1', 'term6'),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )
    )
) );
```

All category/tag parameters are just wrappers for `tax_query`'s to now, so when you use `category__in` or any of the others, you're essentially just taking a shortcut to writing out a `tax_query`.

Comment: Fancy. I so need to read up on these... :)

Comment: Thanks so much for this, but this locks it down so tight I get no posts at all. Does it matter if these are custom post types as well? I did try adding my additional criteria (post type, metas, sorting) but it didn't make any difference.  I'm kin dof thinking I need to re-think my category structure on this.

Comment: @maddy - Could you add the code you're currently using to the question please.