# Can I use $query->set() (in a pre_get_posts() hook) with a custom taxonomy in WP 3?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, pre-get-posts

I can do something like the following with a standard category:

```
$query->set('category__not_in', $term_id);
```

But how do I do the same with a custom taxonomy term?

I'm using Wordpress 3.3.1 if it is relevant.  Thank you. :)

Comment: Just a guess - perhaps I'm supposed to use something like '<custom taxonomy name>__not_in' instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [And/Or Category Query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12252/and-or-category-query)

Comment: Just search for `tax_query` if you want to build a new query. If you want to modify one, then re-build your initial query to use `tax_query`, then add a filter to `posts_clauses` and dump `$pieces`. Then just copy/paste your initial query from the dump, move it to the filter and use the default query (altered via the filter). This saves you a query per request as WP is doing one per default and every custom query is a new one.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not the one who built the query.  I'm trying to exclude a custom category from a particular query, intercepted via pre_get_posts().  So, I didn't build the query, and I can't build it from scratch. :P Ideas?

Comment: "_I'm not the one who built the query_" ... What?! Do you have access to changing files or not?

Comment: Maybe we have different definitions of what is meant by "I'm not the one who built the query".  I'm using the pre_get_posts() to modify queries that originate from Wordpress and other plugins, excluding items that are in a specific term in my custom taxonomy.  So, what I mean is that I can't just build the query back up from scratch; I have to modify it in place.  Unless I'm overlooking something obvious.  Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: No. You don't have to. Just use the filter I told you about. Then hook with a high enough priority...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I just gave up on the '__not_in' approach and went with the following somewhat sneaky solution:

```
//Create the exclusion rule
$new_tax_query = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'x_category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array('y-slug'),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    )
);

//If there is already a tax_query, 'AND' our new rule with the entire existing rule.
$tax_query = $query->get('tax_query');
if(!empty($tax_query)) {
    $new_tax_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        $tax_query,
        $new_tax_query
    );              
}

// var_dump($new_tax_query);

$query->set('tax_query', $new_tax_query);
```

Comment: $tax_query is an object that contains a nested array. You can't override the object with a nested array.

Comment: **NOTE!** AlxVallejo is wrong. `$tax_query` is not an object, `$query` is though (it's an instance of `WP_Query`): http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35196/theres-a-way-to-use-query-settax-query-in-pre-get-posts-filter#comment131164_35263